# software replacement after computer crash

Tags: microsoft-office, license

I had my motherboard destroyed by a spill on my laptop. I was able to retrieve data onto an external drive. I do not plan to repair/restore the laptop and the MS Office Professional software was "Product Key Card - for 1 preloaded PC only. Am I SOL as far as the software is concerned?

Comment: i believe if you call microsoft and explain them what happened, you will be fine.

Answer (score 0):

You could possibly use the product key to install Office on a different computer, but the license terms might forbid that. Unfortunately, the only people who can give a definitive answer are Microsoft. I suggest you call their support line and pose your question to them.

Comment: The OP's question was about Office, not Windows.